# How do I animate moving a list item to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a list and would like to move the item to the top when it's clicked on. Simultaneously, all other items should move down to make space.

That's what I have so far:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li id="one">item-1</li>
  <li id="two">item-2</li>
  <li id="three">item-3</li>
  <li id="four">item-4</li>
</ul>
```

//

```
  $('li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css({ position : 'absolute', top : $(this).position().top });
    var height = $(this).parent().children().first().height();
    var list = $(this).parent();
    $(this).animate({top: '0px'}, { duration: 500, queue: false });

    list.children().each(function( index, element) {
    var $liElement = $(element);
    if($liElement != $(this))
    {
        $liElement.animate({top: height + 'px'}, { duration: 500, queue: false });     
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/5qgnjvdp/

I see the item moving on top but all others don't move at all. What is wrong here?
Should I use `prepend()` to insert the list item on top when the animation is finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not really an "animation", I was working on something some time ago along similar lines. What I ended up using was a `slideUp`, then a `slideDown` to give a sense of animation without actual animation connected to the move.

```js
$('li').click(function() {
        $(this).slideToggle(500, function() {
        $(this).prependTo('#list').slideToggle(500); });
    });
```

```css
li { list-style: none; background: #ddd;padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #aaa; margin: 10px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;color:#fff; }
#list { margin:20px; padding:0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list" data-role="listview">
    <li id="one">item-1</li>
    <li id="two">item-2</li>
    <li id="three">item-3</li>
    <li id="four">item-4</li>
</ul>
```

```
$('li').click(function() {
        $(this).slideToggle(500, function() {
        $(this).prependTo('#list').slideToggle(500); });
    });
```

## [fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/5qgnjvdp/2/)

Again, I realize this isn't really an animation beyond the slide toggles, but it conveys a sense of interactivity similar to an animation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your script.

- When comparing `$liElement != $(this)` you are in the scope of the each function where `this` refers to the current list child, which is the same as `element`. Store the clicked `li` in a variable outside of the looping function and compare with that. Also no need to compare the `$(...)` objects. `element != clickedLi` would suffice.
- When you animate the other `li` elements they don't have `position: absolute` (or relative) so you won't see their movement.
- If you assign the other `li` elements an absolute position you move all of them to the same position, the second row in the list. You could use position relative to move them down. You should just make sure to exclude the elements that come *after* the original position of the clicked `li`.

After the animation is complete you should insert the list item as the first child of the list and then remove the absolute/relative positioning, including the `top` style to make sure it works a second time (and to ensure that the visible representation is in line with the elements' structure.